# php preg_match is not working on url for my condition

Tags: php, preg-match

Php

Variable **$refererUrl**: http://amitberahello.test/checkout/customer/login/user/devbera

and  search  `checkout/customer/login`

```
$refererUrl = 'http://amitberahello.test/checkout/customer/login/user/devbera';

if (preg_match("/checkout/customer/login/", $refererUrl)) {

    // Do something
}
```

Here preg_match condition is not working. Suppose by refer URL has `checkout/customer/login` in this patch then the condition will work.

Comment: Try using a different delimiter like `/` or escape the slashes.

Comment: Sorry, donot understand, Can u please post the answer

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/UAWTc or https://3v4l.org/iJHcf and [Delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: understand your link. Please put the answer your comment as an answer. I will accept the answer: